# file_get_contents and browser session

Tags: php, external, file-get-contents

I have the following code:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://example.com/specific_page");
echo $homepage;
```

The browser already has a session of the site that I need access to, so if I open the url in new tab, the page will be properly loaded.

The issue is that the php script, redirects me to "You are not logged in" page. Note that the url is available even after I restart the browser.

Any ideas how to get content without writing a code that logs in to the site?

Comment: Sounds like xyz.com is using cookies to make persistent data. Your domain (running the php script) simply can't gain access to that session. It's a security measure.

Comment: *"Any ideas how to get content without writing a code that logs in to the site?"* not if the site requires you to log in

Comment: You need to also pass the session credentials / token to the page, e.g. via a Cookie request header or some query parameter on the URL - depending on how that site is handling it's sessions. If sessions are bound to remote IPs, you will likely not be able to hijack the session (what you do could be named session hiacking, read about how it works, the same principles apply here).

Comment: @Dagon, right, but still there is a macro in Word document (i don't have access to the script), which succeeds in opening a new IE window and parsing the data without any credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP runs serversided so it has its own session handling, there is no link to your browsers session. You can use [cURL](http://php.net/curl) and [options](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) like `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to do this. With [cURL](http://php.net/curl) you can login via PHP and keep the PHP session of the website you are requesting. You will find a bunch of examples in the cURL documentation I linked.

Answer (score 3):

It would be an enormous security issue if a website could gain access to your data on arbitrary external websites. Imagine this: `file_get_contents('https://yourbank.com/all-your-details')`.

The only way you can do this is to ask the user for his/her login credentials on the external website and log in manually. This will be unreliable, though, since the authentication process could change (and it's terribly rude to ask someone for his/her password).

This is generally what web service APIs are used for, but if there's none available for the site you're interested in, you're kind of stuck.

---

If you already know the login credentials for the website, then you could hardcode them into the script using the approach outlined by Blauesocke, but this won't work if the details are unique to the current user.

Comment: Seems you are right, as @hakre mentioned I will need to pass the credentials and then request the specific page. I will need to do more research on how to achieve this.